# JPA updates entity with some invalid chars after insert

Tags: java, sql, jpa

It happens when I insert entity from UI and it stores in db for the first time as I have entered. After I refresh page, it updates db and returns me some invalid chars. Something like this:

'8', NULL, NULL, '?e??_??e?', '?e??_o??a??', '2', NULL, '?e??_o?'

Here it is the part of sql log:

```
Hibernate: 
/* insert test.model.Smer
    */ insert 
    into
        test.smer
        (naziv, smer, oblast, obrazovni_profil, odsek_id, stari_naziv, studijska_grupa_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        Smer as generatedAlias0 */ select
            smer0_.smer_id as smer_id1_19_,
            smer0_.naziv as naziv2_19_,
            smer0_.smer as smer3_19_,
            smer0_.oblast as oblast4_19_,
            smer0_.obrazovni_profil as obrazovn5_19_,
            smer0_.odsek_id as odsek_id8_19_,
            smer0_.stari_naziv as stari_na6_19_,
            smer0_.studijska_grupa_id as studijsk7_19_ 
        from
            test.smer smer0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        odsek0_.odsek_id as odsek_id1_13_0_,
        odsek0_.odsek as odsek2_13_0_ 
    from
        test.odsek odsek0_ 
    where
        odsek0_.odsek_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        odsek0_.odsek_id as odsek_id1_13_0_,
        odsek0_.odsek as odsek2_13_0_ 
    from
        test.odsek odsek0_ 
    where
        odsek0_.odsek_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        odsek0_.odsek_id as odsek_id1_13_0_,
        odsek0_.odsek as odsek2_13_0_ 
    from
        test.odsek odsek0_ 
    where
        odsek0_.odsek_id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        Odsek as generatedAlias0 */ select
            odsek0_.odsek_id as odsek_id1_13_,
            odsek0_.odsek as odsek2_13_ 
        from
            test.odsek odsek0_
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        test.model.Smer */ update
            test.smer 
        set
            naziv=?,
            smer=?,
            oblast=?,
            obrazovni_profil=?,
            odsek_id=?,
            stari_naziv=?,
            studijska_grupa_id=? 
        where
            smer_id=?
```

Comment: Firstly,  you need to check what values send to database after you click the refresh.

Comment: UI is UTF-8 db not? Can you show what should be there instead of `?` character? What is expected?

Comment: '8', NULL, NULL, 'Software Development', 'Software Developer', '2', NULL, 'Computer Science'

Comment: Everything is UTF-8

Comment: yeap either the format is lost during insert or during select , so check both cases by printing localy in UTF-8 format as suggested

Comment: I will try to explain by steps, this doesn't matter with UI. I save object to DB, and first select after that returns same results as I have entered. After I refresh page, JPA is doing update on entity and inserting some invalid data and that is reflected in db. Everything is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working with?

Double check to see if the page is utf-8 (or whatever suitable) and the database field must be the same char-set then check the received values before sending them to DB to check where that happens exactly.

Comment: Java, Spring Boot, JPA, MySQL... everything is utf-8, and the problem is when JPA byself updates entity with no reason.